# Version control approach for a repo that uses custom plugins

Tags: git, version-control, open-source

I'm getting into open source projects and I have a workflow issue I'm not sure how to fix.

Scenario:

- I have a web framework repo I eventually want to make open source.
- I use this same repo for a separate personal website. As I build the personal site, I can identify issues and push them directly to the open source project.

Problem:
For the personal website, I'd like to use some generated plugins (like Google analytics). But I don't want to check those in because it's autogenerated code based on my Google account.

- Do I `.gitignore` the files that I want to customize with plugin code (e.g., contact page)? That doesn't seem right because then anyone else pulling wouldn't get a contact page?
- Make a copy of the default file (like `contact_page_default.html`). Then `.gitignore` the main contact_page. In the instructions, tell people to rename the default contact page when they want to use it. Seems like a usability nightmare.
- Fork the repo? That seemed like a bad idea since I never actually plan to push those plugin changes back to the main repo.

What is the best way to continue to push/pull updates from the open source repo as I find them and also have changes specific to my personal site?